# What is the difference between normal mode and command line mode?

Tags: command-line, normal-mode

Normal mode is also called command mode, and is different from command line mode.

It seems both can be used for `:` commands, but what is the difference?

Answer (score 6):

`:` is a normal-mode key-sequence (command) that makes a switch into one of command-line submodes.

> From `:h :`
>
> Command-line mode is used to enter Ex commands (":"), search patterns
>   ("/" and "?"), and filter commands ("!").

So in command-line mode `:` is just a prompt that shows you're allowed to input one Ex-command and then get back to the Normal mode (so it differs from the true Ex-mode).

Comment: I see, I know both modes pretty well, but confused myself severely when reading the help, it seems... I assumed `command` means the same in both mode names, but only one of them means ex command. And there would be good reasons to call ex mode the normal mode, because it existed before command mode.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel For that reason we'd have called "vi-mode" instead of "normal" mode. But nowadays "vi-mode" is really "normal", while "true Ex" is almost never used.

Comment: Yes, "vi-mode" is the right name. I suspect scrolling randomly through vim help is inherently risky... (I feel very ''at home" in vim, and normally in the help too...)

Answer (score 6):

Normal mode is the mode you are in when you start Vim and the mode you should spend the most of time in. From this mode you can easily invoke other modes (`v` for *visual*, `i` for *insert*, `:` for ***command line*** and so on).

Everything you press in *normal mode* can be some sort of command. `dd`? It's a command saying "*delete current line*". Hence *command mode*.

In *command line mode* you use Ex and search commands, like `:s/a/b/g` or `/pattern`. For them to take effect you need to press "Return"* (after which you get back to *normal mode* - there is also *Ex mode*, where after pressing "Return" you stay in *command line*).

In big approximation: *normal* (*command*) *mode* is for keybindings and *command line* is for "shell" commands (similarity to *Bash*, *Zsh*, *sh*, *CMD* etc.)

* return, enter, `<CR>`

Comment: I know both modes pretty well, but confused myself severely when reading the help, it seems... I assumed `command` means the same in both mode names, but only one of them means `ex command`. And there would be good reasons to call ex mode the normal mode, because it existed before command mode. And good reasons to call normal mode vi-mode. I suspect scrolling randomly through vim help is inherently risky...  (I feel very ''at home" in vim, and normally in the help too...)